# Inserting into two SQL tables that reference each other without having to execute separate queries?

Tags: c++, sqlite, insert

So I have two sqlite tables (managed using C++), as shown below:

```
Table A:
primaryKey (Primary key auto increment)
b_ref (int REFERENCES TableB(primaryKey))
added_info (text)
```

and

```
Table B:
primaryKey (Primary key auto increment)
info (text)
```

Lets say periodically I want to insert something into B and then ALWAYS follow by inserting something into A.  Is there a way I can insert into table B and have sql return the primary key so that I can quickly insert into A without having to run a query on table B?

So in basic terms, I'm currently doing:

```
Insert into A.
QUERY A to find the primary key of what I just inserted.
Insert into B (passing the results from the above query)
```

What I'd like to do is something like:

```
Insert into A and retain the primary key for this insert
Insert into B (passing the primary key from the above insert)
```

Is something like this possible? If I manually defined what the primary key was (instead of using autoincrement), could I just pass this manually defined value to both inserts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't use the auto increment feature, then you could manage the primary keys yourself and simply pass the same value to both methods. The only downside to this is that you now must know what primary keys are available to perform an insert.

If this is a one to one relationship between tables A and B, then it would likely be more efficient to combine them into a single table and enter all the data into that table at once.

Comment: I think I will go this route and manage my primary keys myself.  I'm not able to combine the tables due to other issues with the problem, but I think I've found a way to guarantee unique primary keys.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

SQLite has the function [sqlite3_last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html) for this:

> The sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(D) interface returns the [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) of the most recent successful [INSERT](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) into a rowid table or virtual table on database connection D.

Alternatively, you could use the [last_insert_rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#last_insert_rowid) SQL function.